# Swagger POST request not working after AUTH

Tags: curl, post, authorization, swagger

I created swagger documentation for one of our APIs which was nicely working until hitting a major roadblock with Basic Auth on all of the POST requests.

After adding the security section and defining the POST body everything looks sweet, the example body is generated and looks the way it should. However when "Authorize"-ing the request and clicking send a *working* curl statement is generated (after pasting it to a terminal and pressing enter it returns the results as expected), but the "response" part of the page says "no response" and the repose code is 0.

The thing that is confusing me is that I would expect the thing to be able to submit the same curl line as it just have generated?

Sorry, but I cannot post the exact API call, but here's something similar in principle so that one can have a basic idea of what I'm trying to do.

My security section looks straightforward:

```
securityDefinitions:
  Basic:
    description: "Use pre-provided API credentials here."
    type: "basic"
    name: Authorization
    in: header
```

The body of the desired POST request is defined in multiple referenced schemas under definitions like so:

```
definitions:
  postrequestbody:
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
      postcode:
        type: string
      someotherthing:
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/someotherthing"
        type: object
  someotherthing:
    properties:
      someID:
        enum:
          - b64encodedvalue
        type: string
      yetanotherreferencedobject:
        items:
          $ref: "#/definitions/yetanotherreferencedobject"
        type: array
      somethignwithyears:
        enum:
          - "2012"
        type: string
```

This is a bit more complex than this example, but in principle the idea is the same with more sub-objects and to re-usably represent the structure of each call. Some of the referenced objects are used in different POST requests.

Based on all this a valid curl line is constructed including the auth header.

There some GET endpoints in the same definition which work fine *before* I press "Authorise" on any of the POST methods. After the user and password is entered and "Authorise"-d the GET requests also stop working and say "no content" and reposes code 0.

Has anyone seen anything remotely similar to this and could give any pointers on where to look as I ran out of ideas after 2 days of searching for a solution.

Thanks for reading all this - hopefully I gave enough detail so that the problem can be understood.

Any ideas highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Swagger UI or Swagger Editor, and which exactly version? Does your server have [CORS](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#cors-support) enabled, as required by Swagger UI/Editor? If you open the browser dev tools > Network and record the request, does the request contain the Authorization header?

Comment: Hi Helen, I haven't used Swagger Editor. I created a YAML file based off the documentation and using it in swagger UI.

Comment: Hi again Helen, yes CORS is set up. Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization << like this. I believe it should be sufficient to pass Authorization headers where ever I choose to.

Comment: Sounds like after Authorization it still tries to submit an OPTIONS request without the headers. api*****.com resource-type-xhr OPTIONS HTTPS 401. Does that mean my API should listen for non-auth OPTIONS requests so that the preflight can run successfully and then it will be possible to submit the actual request? :O